# Using a lambda function in python

Tags: python, lambda

Is there a way to convert a function to a lambda function (automatically) in python? Something like:

```
def func(arg):
    print("Hi", arg)
```

==>

```
lambda arg: compile(func) # <== something like this
```

Comment: Could you explain the context of your question? The answer is `lambda x: func(x)`, but why would you want to do that?

Comment: Why? Lambdas are just one line functions. There is nothing a lambda can do that a normal function can't.

Comment: To use in something like a sort/map/filter method I suppose, though I think the first answer answers the question.

Comment: Why? In any case, it is trivial to wrap a function with another.

Comment: @danielroseman Lambdas are _nameless_ one line functions, in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions in Python are first-class citizens of the language. This means that a function can be manipulated as if it was a data value. Thus, a function can be passed to another function as an argument, or returned from a function as a result. This is referred to as *higher-order programming*.

Now, both the `def` and the `lambda` keywords define such function values. The main difference is that `def` assigns a name to such a function, whereas lambdas are anonymous functions. Another difference is that lambdas are limited to one line of code (although there are languages where this is not the case).

For example, here are two equivalent functions, one defined with `def`, the other with `lambda`:

```python
def say_hello(name):
    print('Hi ', name)

lambda name: print('Hi ', name)
```

Another way to interpret the `def` keyword is as follows:

```python
say_hello = lambda name: print('Hi ', name)
```

Although such code is highly discouraged.

In essence, both of these two functions are (nearly) equivalent data values, but in the snippet above, the one defined with `def` could later be called, since it has a name and we can therefore later access it. The one defined by `lambda` cannot, since it does not have a name, and is thus immediately lost if not assigned to a variable or passed to another function, say `f`, as an argument, where it is then given a name in `f`'s local scope as per the `f`'s parameters.

However, lambdas are useful in cases where we do not want to clutter up our scope with new, short functions that are only passed to another function as an argument:

```python
map(lambda x: x * 2, [1, 2, 3])
# >>> [2, 4, 6]
```

If you already have a function defined with `def` that does the multiplication shown above, as would be the case in your example, e.g.:

```python
def double(x):
    return x * 2
```

Then you can simply refer to this function by name in the call to map:

```python
map(double, [1, 2, 3])
# >>> [2, 4, 6]
```

**In short: There is no need to "compile a function to a lambda", a lambda is just a special case of a function which is not given a name. Refer to your function by name instead.**

P.S.: Don't use `map` and `filter`, use [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) instead, as they are considered more pythonic.

Answer (score -1):

You can make yours easily:

```
def auto_lam(f):
  return lambda *args, **kwargs: f(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then to use it:

```
mylam = auto_lam(func)
```

In this form, you can see that this is quite useless because you are simply calling the same function, but wrapping functions is something that is very common in python because it allows us to modify the behaviour of the function. These are called **decorator functions**.

For example:

```
def logging_func(f):
    def do_work(*args, **kwargs):
        print ("You called me")
        res = f(*args, **kwargs)
        print ("Finished")
        return res
    return do_work
```

Now you can wrap your existing function with this one like so:

```
@logging_func
def func(arg):
   print("Hi", arg)
```

Now every time you call `func`, it will log something before and after. I argue this is a better use of function wrappers than one that simply gives you back the same function.

Comment: But there is no possible use for this. You could just use `func` directly.